Get user Text data from linked blocks
I need to get a list of all the blocks present in a file and if they are linked retrieve all TextUserData.
I achieve the result with this script
import os 
import Rhino

import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs 
import scriptcontext from scriptcontext 
import doc


active_file = "%s%s" % (rs.DocumentPath(),rs.DocumentName())
print("Start working on " + os.path.basename(active_file))

def printDocAttributes():
    val = rs.GetDocumentUserText()
    if val:
        for p in val:
            print("Key: ",p)
            print("Value: ",rs.GetDocumentUserText(p)) 
printDocAttributes()
print("block") 
print(rs.BlockCount())
#
document_paths=[] 
#
for b in rs.BlockNames() :
    print("** Block ** ",b)   
    bi=rs.BlockInstances(b)
    for bo in rs.BlockObjects(b):
        print("Block Instance", bo)
        print("Usertext", rs.GetUserText(bo))
    block_path = rs.BlockPath(b)
    print(os.path.basename(block_path))
    document_paths.append(block_path) 
#
for p in document_paths:
    print("Get data from ", os.path.basename(p))
    Rhino.RhinoDoc.Open(p)
    printDocAttributes() 
print("End") 
#
Rhino.RhinoDoc.Open(active_file)

but this open and close the file, and it's not something I would like it append
any idea in how to solve it ?
Regards
